# MVC 3 - DB Context - Web.Config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dbcontext

How can I share my DBcontext in my web.config without creating multiple connections?

```
WEB.config:
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="daC_Companies" connectionString="Data Source=10.0.2.100;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXXXXx;Password=XXXXXXXX;Persist Security Info=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>


Data Access:
        public class daC_Companies : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<ClassLibrary.Companies.C_Companies> dbsetC_Companies { get; set; }
        }
```

And then I have a class called C_Companies referenced above. It works fine but I don't want to have a new DBContext for every class I want to access.

Answer (score 1):

The DbContext should be specific to the database, not to the object.  To add a reference to more db tables, add them as properties into the daC_Companies object:

```
    public class daC_Companies : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ClassLibrary.Companies.C_Companies> dbsetC_Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassLibrary.Companies.Object2> Object2s { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassLibrary.Companies.Object3> Object3s { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClassLibrary.Companies.Object4> Object4s { get; set; }
    }
```